# Is there any way to convert the constitutional parsing to dependency parsing in natural language processing

Tags: nlp

I wanna know that is there any way to convert the constitutional parsing to dependency parsing in natural language processing or separate grammar has to be written for the dependency parsing.

Is there any analogy between constitutional parsing and dependency parsing that would lead to their interconversion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw this article once, thought it can help:

We first describe the automatic conversion of the French Treebank (Abeillé and Barrier, 2004), a constituency treebank, into typed projective dependency trees.
— http://hnk.ffzg.hr/bibl/lrec2010/pdf/392_Paper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You may also check the paper "[Generating Typed Dependency Parses from Phrase Structure Parses](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/LREC06_dependencies.pdf)". This uses the rule-based approach.